# Updating 1 table with information from another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables, with one being regularly added to, but also a number of rows being updated through an SSIS package, over which I have no control. Both tables are 150.000 ish rows.

I need to add new rows from the production table to the production_history table, but I also need to update the _history table with the data from production (about 15 columns), if it already exists in _history.

Adding new lines is fairly straight forward, but I struggle with the update. I think I figured out a way to do it and I am testing it with just 1 column,, but that query has already been running for 40 minutes for just 1 field, which of course takes to long, and won't work if I add the others

The query I have now is:

```
update production_history

set [KGMS] = (select KGMS from Production prod where  CONVERT(varchar(250), prod.FARM_ID) + CONVERT(varchar(250), prod.COLLECTION_DATE)  =

-- below provides an list of the unique pair but in the join of prod and history
(CONVERT(varchar(250), production_history.FARM_ID) + CONVERT(varchar(250), production_history.COLLECTION_DATE))
)
```

I do not have a primary/foreignkey, but the combination of farm_id and collection_date is unique

I am trying to figure out of there is a way to make the query more efficient, perhaps by using an inner join, but I cannot get the syntax right

What I have so far is:

```
UPDATE Production_History 

SET KGMS = production.KGMS 

from

(select KGMS from production

where CONVERT(varchar(250), Production.FARM_ID) + CONVERT(varchar(250), Production.COLLECTION_DATE) in

-- below provides an list of the unique pair but in the join of prod and history
(SELECT CONVERT(varchar(250), a.FARM_ID) + CONVERT(varchar(250), a.COLLECTION_DATE) 

  FROM Production_History b

  Inner join Production a on a.Farm_id = b.Farm_id and a.Collection_date = b.Collection_date))
```

But SQL Server is complaining about a syntax error near ')'. I am just not seeing it, and I am not even sure if this will make the query any quicker anyway

Does anyway have an idea how to efficiently tackle this scenario, I have also thought that maybe an "and" statement, limiting the results if certain values are equal, but from the BA's I hear there is fluctuation in basically most columns.

Help much appreciated!

Comment: You need to check the docs for the update statement, you need to have a primary table (not a sub-query) which you are updating. You can then join on that, but need to alias your tables for the update. Finally, your "unique" identifier for your row is most likely what is causing performance issues, because SQL Server has to calculate that for every row in both your tables before it can begin to join them, and indexes won't help unless you have indexed the combination (which from what you say you haven't).

Comment: Even if the two columns were indexed in each of their tables, concatenating values like that to compare between tables leads to full table scans, so it's unsurprising that it's slow. 150,000 rows x 150,000 rows = 22,500,000,000 comparisons in the worst case. Have you considered adding persisted computed columns (holding the concatenated values) to each table and indexing them?

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but what's wrong with just: `UPDATE t 
SET KGMS = p.KGMS 
from Production_History t
INNER JOIN Production p
 on p.Farm_id = t.Farm_id
 and p.Collection_date = t.Collection_date`

Comment: @siggemannen You are spot on, there is absolutely no reason to not join like that .. I had a serious case of tunnelvision!

This speeds it up immensely.

This is the answer to my question.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning That is certainly a good idea as well! Something I may implement in the production_history table anyway, since that is a new one I am building. It will at least create a unique key of sorts. 

I am hesitant to touch the original production table, since it is an undocumented legacy mess, which is referenced in at least 2 views that I am aware of at the moment. (I'm not one to F around and find out in something that is in daily usein production :) ) 

Thanks for that idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer from @siggemannen is the correct one, thanks for pointing that out. Now the query runs fast across all fields and columns.

---

"
Maybe i'm missing something but what's wrong with just:

```
UPDATE t  SET KGMS = p.KGMS  from Production_History t INNER JOIN Production p  on  p.Farm_id = t.Farm_id   and p.Collection_date = t.Collection_date
'''
"
-----
```